# Wordpress, jquery load php file not found

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm loading php files dynamically via jquery/ajax into a Wordpress page template.

I've got the following which works on a local server but when I upload to my test site online I get a 404 error in the console when loading the file.

Summarised code:

```
var root = location.protocol + '//' + location.host;

$(".button-book").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#container').load(root+'/wp-content/themes/PL14-Base/inc/bookings-swiss.php');
});
```

You can actually see the development site [here](http://pl.mrjonnywood.com/contacts/). Click the first 'Make a reservation' button to see the issue.

Update:
I've changed the code to use the exact urls for clarity
The file can be found at [the correct url](http://pl.mrjonnywood.com/wp-content/themes/PL14-Base/inc/bookings-swiss.php) when called directly in the browser.

Comment: double check the url that probably where the problem is.

Comment: @NetaMeta I can load the url successfully in the browser, just get a 404 when called dynamically.

Comment: is the URL on the same host ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this inside a php file? if yes Please use the `get_template_directory_uri();` helper

```
 var root = location.protocol + '//' + location.host;

 $(".button-book").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#container').load('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/inc/loaded-file.php');
 });
```

Comment: No, it's inside javascript

Comment: the js file is in `wp-content/themes/PL14-Base/library/js/` and is called via `functions.php` to the footer of the site

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get this working by using `<?php require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php'); ?>` at the top of the loaded php file, but this is a dirty fix. Would prefer to know the correct way to do this.

Comment: whats you're trying to achieve ? are you trying to find a way to do ajax calls the proper way with WP ?

Comment: @NetaMeta partly yes, but it's a bit more complex than that. I'm calling a php file dynamically that contains several Wordpress GetText echo calls `_e()` in order to translate content using the wpml plugin.

Comment: Do you know how to set up normal ajax "router" for WP ? the right way ? i am asking that because i am not sure about your question however it seems like you're trying to do ajax

Comment: @NetaMeta no, but that's what I'm currently looking into as well

Answer (score 0):

In you main plugin or function php or wherever you'll do the following to attach a global variable to a certain script

```
$main_js_namespace = array(
    'ajaxURL' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
    'data' => array(
        'action' => '',
        'method' => '',
        'post' => '',
    )
);

// script handler, javascript global variable name,
wp_localize_script('bec_script_handle','gVariable',$main_js_namespace);
```

This class class handle the ajax calls.

```
class ajaxClass {
    public function __construct() {
        // ajaxClass can be whatever you want..
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxClass', array($this, 'handle_ajax'));
        add_action('wp_ajax_ajaxClass', array($this, 'handle_ajax'));
    }

    // this simply handle the routing of the functions.
    public function handle_ajax() {
        if(isset($_POST['method'])) {
            $method = $_POST['method'];
            if(method_exists($this, $method)) {
                if(isset($_POST['post']) && $_POST['post'] != 'false') {
                    parse_str(stripslashes($_POST['post']), $post);
                    $request = call_user_func(array($this, $method), $post);
                    echo (is_array($request)) ? json_encode($request) : $request;
                } else {
                    $request = call_user_func(array($this, $method));
                    echo (is_array($request)) ? json_encode($request) : $request;
                }
            } else {
                $json['success'] = false;
                $json['msg'] = __CLASS__.'::'.$method.' not found, define first! por favor..';
                echo json_encode($json);
            }
        }
        exit;
    }

    /*
     * bla
     * */
    public function someAjaxCall($post){
       $toRetun = "whatever Response You Want";
        return $toRetun;
    }

}

$ajaxClass = new ajaxClass();
```

// this is how i would make the calls to that script

```
    // the action we chose 
    gVariable.data.action = 'ajaxClass';

    // whatever method in the ajax class you want to access
    gVariable.data.method = 'get_table_schema';

    // whatever variable/data you want to pass
    gVariable.data.post = 'tableName=' + tableName;

    this functions is  a async false and ones done give you an object with the result however any other would work.
    var getData = function(){
        var getData = {};
        var setData = function(data) {
            getData = data;
        };

        return function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: gVariable.ajaxURL,
                type: "post",
                async: false,
                dataType:'json',
                data:becGlobal.data,
                success: function (data) {
                    setData(data);
                },
                error : function (data) {
                    setData(data);
                }
            });
            return getData;
        }
    }

    getData()();
</script>
```

Comment: thanks @NetaMeta but that's way beyond me. I think I need to learn more about this first.

Comment: This is very basic. just looks complicated, however suit yourself

Comment: I appreciate the help, I just can't apply this to my situation. That said, I didn't clearly define the whole problem in my original question. I've detailed it in full here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/139896/load-a-form-via-jquery-ajax-that-contains-strings-for-translation-wpml I'll be looking at the Wordpress AJAX API for reference and trying to work with your example