# Bootstrap Modal Popup Jquery Post validation how?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

I am trying to create a popup and form with validation but for some reason my modal is not appearing.

```
<div id="thanks" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Redeem Points</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
     <form class="form-horizontal"  class="contact" name="commentform" method="post" action="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/sendredeempoints.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
            <h3>You may only redeem the maxium points of : <?php echo $maxpoints;?></h3>
                <input type="hidden" name="playerid" value="<?php echo $playerId;;?>" />
                  <input type="number"  valuemax="<?php echo $maxpoints;?>" name="points" class="form-control" placeholder="How many points do you wish to redeem." />                  
                   <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="Comments">Comments?</label>


        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <button title="" data-original-title="" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-custom pull-right" id="send_btn">Send</button><div style="top: -4px; left: 279px; display: block;" class="popover fade right in"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 style="display: none;" class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content">Thank You</div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div><!-- End of Modal body -->
    </div><!-- End of Modal content -->
    </div><!-- End of Modal dialog -->
</div><!-- End of Modal -->
```

I am using the jquery below to go to my processing file but for some reason my modal dialog is not appearing its just brigning the see thru div up but no dialog?? And yes i do have lattest bootstrap and js installed in my headers of theme

```
<script>
 $(function () {
     //twitter bootstrap script
     $("button#submit").click(function () {
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "process.php",
             data: $('form.contact').serialize(),
             success: function (msg) {
                 $("#thanks").html(msg)
                 $("#form-content").modal('hide');
             },
             error: function () {
                 alert("failure");
             }
         });
     });
 });
</script>
```

Process.php

```
<?php         
$playerid = $_POST['playerid']; // required        
$points = $_POST['points']; // required
$mymessage = $_POST['userMessage']; // required    
$email_from='davidbuckleyni@gmail.com';
$email_subject = $_POST['mysubject'];
$email_to =$_POST['toEmail'];

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $mymessage, $headers);
?>
```

**Edit**
Ok the div is now appearing ok but it just reffuses to do the ajax request bringing me to a page not found in wordpress even though the php is in the same directory as this php file.

Comment: with code in question this is how the modal looks like http://jsfiddle.net/v1tv4x1q/1/ no problem there

Comment: @Shehary yes but what i meen its its not finding the php file at all yet i have it saved in the same directory of my wordpress theme.

Comment: @Shehary pleas see my last edit

Comment: trigger the Ajax call after modal shown, use bootstrap modal event listener http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events,  `show` or `shown` and handle Ajax call inside listener.

Comment: this will give you the idea http://jsfiddle.net/v1tv4x1q/2/ good luck

Comment: @Shehary bootstrap is nothuing to do with why it cant find the file !

Comment: I agree with you that it has nothing to do with bootstrap my bad may be I need another cup of coffee :)

Comment: @Shehary its still not finding the file :-(

Comment: why you have `action="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/sendredeempoints.php"` in form

Comment: that was in my orignal post i have since removed that and added ur code all i have in my form tag is this.

  <form class="form-horizontal"  class="contact" name="commentform" method="post"  >

Comment: since you are using wordpress, may be this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786614/wordpress-jquery-load-php-file-not-found

Comment: @Shehary its a bit beyond my scope buddy

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap modal cannot show itself. If you want to show the Modal you have to call it.

Show modal when clicking a button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#thanks">
    Show modal
</button>
```

Show modal after page loaded:

```
$(window).load(function () {
        $('#thanks').modal('show');
    })
```

Comment: that is not the issue here would mark it down as u obv didnt read the eidts